# Convert .crt + .key files to X509Certificate2 programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509

I have a .crt certificate and a .key private key file on a Linux machine. The private key is in encrypted PKCS#8 format (BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY...). I would like to import these into an X509Certificate2 object for further use. Since we're on Linux, we're using .NET Core 2.2 (we cannot migrate to 3.0 yet).

I have explored a few possible solutions, detailed below:

1. Use `openssl` to convert the files to a .pfx and import that using X509Certificate2

   - I do not want to use this option since I don't want to execute shell code from within C#. I would like the solution to be completely programmatically achieved in C#.
2. Use the C# BouncyCastle libraries to do either:

   - A conversion of both the certificate and the key to .pfx (as above), or
   - Importing the certificate and private key separately and using [`X509Certificate2.CopyWithPrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.copywithprivatekey?view=netframework-4.8) to combine them.
   - However, I cannot find an API for the C# version of BouncyCastle, so I'm not sure what methods I could possibly use to do this.
3. Some other programmatic method in C# that I'm missing here

Essentially, the end goal is to obtain an X509Certificate2 object from the .crt and .key files. Any help/insight into what approach to use, or even a pointer to helpful BouncyCastle documentation, would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.import?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The Import methods provided don't seem to allow for handling of just a certificate and a private key. They either take just the certificate or a certificate, password, and KeyStorageFlags, neither of which fits my use case.

Comment: It looks like you can just set the property : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_PrivateKey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, though not as friendly as it could be, in .NET Core 3.0:

```
private static byte[] UnPem(string pem)
{
    // This is a shortcut that assumes valid PEM
    // -----BEGIN words-----\nbase64\n-----END words-----
    const string Dashes = "-----";
    int index0 = pem.IndexOf(Dashes);
    int index1 = pem.IndexOf('\n', index0 + Dashes.Length);
    int index2 = pem.IndexOf(Dashes, index1 + 1);

    return Convert.FromBase64String(pem.Substring(index1, index2 - index1));
}

...

string keyPem = File.ReadAllText("private.key");
byte[] keyDer = UnPem(keyPem);
X509Certificate2 certWithKey;

using (X509Certificate2 certOnly = new X509Certificate2("certificate.cer"))
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    // For "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY"
    rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(keyDer, out _);
    certWithKey = certOnly.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
}

using (certWithKey)
{
    Console.WriteLine(certWithKey.HasPrivateKey);
}
```

RSA private keys can be in three different formats, and you need to call the correct import for each one:

- "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY": ImportPkcs8PrivateKey
- "BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY": ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey
- "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY": ImportRSAPrivateKey

Comment: While I was trying to avoid moving my entire project to .NET 3.0, BouncyCastle didn't end up working. This is the solution I went with. Thanks!

Comment: This answer, unfortunately, won't work if you must support .NET Standard 2.0 or older as neither the ImportXXX() methods or CopyWithPrivateKey() are available before 2.1 (.NET Core 3.0+ or .NET 5.0 Preview).

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 5 this got as easy as can be:

```
var certificate =
  X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(
    crtFile,
    Path.ChangeExtension(crtFile, "key"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Crt files and pem files can be used interchangeably in the code if they're not in the DER format.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile (string certPemFilePath, string keyPemFilePath)
```

In the certPemFilePath, you can use the path to your crt file.